# Multi Bit TCP Request in Java

Tags: java, tcp, bit, operations

I am trying to make a tcp request in Java to a existing TCP server that is already available. 
the interface specification is:

```
Field           Length      Type
Length          2 bytes     16-bits binary
Message ID      1 byte      8-bits binary
MSGTYPE         1 byte      8-bits binary
Variable1       4 bytes     32-bits binary
Variable2       30 bytes    ASCII
Variable3       1 byte      8-bits binary
```

I understand how to convert a String to Binary using BigInteger.

```
String testing = "Test Binary";
byte[] bytes = testing.getBytes();
BigInteger bi = new BigInteger(bytes);
System.out.println(bi.toString(2));
```

My Understanding is that if i wanted to make a TCP request i would first

1. need to convert each binary to a string
2. append the values to a StringBuffer.

Unfortunately my understanding is limited so i wanted some advice on creating the TCP request correctly.

Comment: Why don't you consider `byte` as binary?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I wouldn't use String (as you have binary data), StringBuffer (ever), or BigInteger (as it not what its designed for).

Assuming you have a Big Endian data stream I would use DataOutputStream

```
DataOutptuStream out = new DataOutputStream(new BufferedOutputStream(socket.getOutputStream()));

out.writeShort(length);
out.write(messageId);
out.write(msgtype);
out.write((var1+"\0\0\0\0").substring(0, 4).getBytes("ISO-8859-1"));
out.write(var2.getBytes("ISO-8859-1"));
out.write(var2);

out.flush(); // optionally.
```

If you have a little endian protocol, you need to use ByteBuffer in which case I would use a blocking NIO SocketChannel.

BTW I would use `ISO-8859-1` (8-bit bytes) rather than `US-ASCII` (7-bit bytes)

Comment: Thanks for the info, if the value for var1 is a string, how would i be able to convert the input into the bit (32 bit) format. So the bits dont matter? as the inputs originally would be string.

Comment: I have added an example with padding and truncation if the string is less than or more than 4 bytes long.

Comment: Thanks Peter, I was really heading the wrong way with my original thought process, so thanks for clearing things up. So if i wanted to have  16 bit and 32 bit strings converted then i would use getBytes("UTF-16") and getBytes("UTF-32"). is that correct? or is there an ISO equivalent?

Comment: You can use those, but UTF-8 is likely to be a better choice. There might be an ISO equivalent but using UTF-n is likely to be clearer.

Answer (score 0):

You are going into the wrong direction. The fact that the message specification states that, for example, first field is a 16 bit binary doesn't mean that you will send a binary string. You will just send an (unsigned?) 16 bit number which will be, as a matter of fact, codified in binary since it's internal representation can just be that one.

When writing onto a socket through an `DataOutputStream` like in

```
int value = 123456;
out.writeInt(value);
```

you are already writing it in binary.

Comment: its worth noting that `out.write(123456);` is the same as `out.write((byte) 123456);` which might not be what you intended.

Comment: Yup, I intended writeInt. Thanks for noticing it.